# Limiting Keys in Type Safe Heterogenous Containers

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to use the generic type safe container pattern, described in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, but would like to restrict the classes which can be used as keys by using an enum.  Below is the code from Joshua's book.

```
public class Favorites {

  private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

  public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
    if (type == null)
      throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
    favorites.put(type, instance);
  }

  public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(favorites.get(type));
  }

}
```

I would like to write a similar class, but limit the keys to say "Dog.class", and "Cat.class".  Ideally, the acceptable keys would be described by an enum, and the "RestrictedFavorites" class would take members of the enum as keys.  I'm not sure if I can get the compiler to do all these things for me (type safety, restriction by enum, generality), but if anybody has a suggestion, I'm all ears.  Below is attempt V1, which uses runtime checks rather than compile time checks, and is not entirely satisfactory.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
/**
 * Attempt V1 At a "RestrictedFavorites" class
 */
public class RestrictedFavorites {

  public static enum RestrictedKey {

    STRING(String.class),
    INTEGER(Integer.class);

    private static Set<Class<?>> classes;
    static {
      classes = new HashSet<>();
      for (RestrictedKey key: values()) {
        classes.add(key.getKlass());
      }
    }

    private final Class<?> klass;

    RestrictedKey(Class<?> klass) {
      this.klass = klass;
    }

    public Class<?> getKlass() {
      return klass;
    }

    public static boolean isValidClassKey(Class<?> klass) {
      return classes.contains(klass);
    }

  }

  private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites =  new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

  //Ideally would use compile time checking
  public <T> void putFavorite(RestrictedKey key, T instance) {
    if (key == null) throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
    if (!key.getKlass().equals(instance.getClass())) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "The type of the key must match the type of the instance");
    }
    favorites.put(key.getKlass(), instance);
  }

  //Ideally would take a RestrictedKey as an argument
  public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> key) {
    if (!RestrictedKey.isValidClassKey(key)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "The key must be a member of RestrictedKeys");
    }
    return key.cast(favorites.get(key));
  }

}
```

Below are some unit tests to verify that my class is doing roughly what I want it to:

```
public class RestrictedFavoritesTest extends TestCase {

  public void testPutFavorite() {
    RestrictedFavorites myFavorites = new RestrictedFavorites();
    myFavorites.putFavorite(RestrictedKey.INTEGER, 1);
    myFavorites.putFavorite(RestrictedKey.STRING, "hey");
    int expectedInt = myFavorites.getFavorite(Integer.class);
    assertEquals(1, expectedInt);
    String expectedString = myFavorites.getFavorite(String.class);
    assertEquals("hey", expectedString);
  }

  public void testPutFavorite_wrongType() {
    RestrictedFavorites myFavorites = new RestrictedFavorites();
    try {
      myFavorites.putFavorite(RestrictedKey.INTEGER, "hey");
      fail();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException expected) {}
  }

  public void testPutFavorite_wrongClass() {
    RestrictedFavorites myFavorites = new RestrictedFavorites();
    try {
      myFavorites.getFavorite(Boolean.class);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException expected) {}
  }

}
```

Comment: Use the `enum` as a key in the `Map` and store the `Class` type in a property of the `enum`.

Comment: I tried this approach.  I've added an example to my question, but it doesn't compile.  I'll iterate and post a better version if I can figure something out.

Comment: In your `getFavorite` cast the return type to a `T`. If you want to restrict the instances your `Map` can hold without some common parent class you will have to rely on runtime checks. You could put that method into your `enum` too - it would tidy the code a little.

Comment: Is it an option to have the favorite classes implement a marker interface instead?

Answer (score 1):

Answer (to my own question).  Don't use Enums.  Because enums can't be generic.  Instead, create a class to represent the restricted keys, and restrict access to the constructor.  Enumerate the valid keys as fields.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RestrictedFavorites {

  private static final class RestrictedKey<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    private RestrictedKey(Class<T> type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    private Class<T> getMyType() {
      return this.type;
    }
  }

  public static final RestrictedKey<String> STRING_KEY =
      new RestrictedKey<>(String.class);
  public static final RestrictedKey<Integer> INTEGER_KEY =
      new RestrictedKey<>(Integer.class);

  private final Map<RestrictedKey<?>, Object> favorites =
      new HashMap<RestrictedKey<?>, Object>();

  public <T> void putFavorite(RestrictedKey<T> key, T instance) {
    favorites.put(key, instance);
  }

  public <T> T getFavorite(RestrictedKey<T> key) {
    return key.getMyType().cast(favorites.get(key));
  }

}
```

And the unit tests:

```
public class RestrictedFavoritesTest extends TestCase {

  public void testPutFavorite() {
    RestrictedFavorites myFavorites = new RestrictedFavorites();
    myFavorites.putFavorite(RestrictedFavorites.STRING_KEY, "hey");
    myFavorites.putFavorite(RestrictedFavorites.INTEGER_KEY, 1);
    assertEquals(new Integer(1), myFavorites.getFavorite(RestrictedFavorites.INTEGER_KEY));
    assertEquals("hey", myFavorites.getFavorite(RestrictedFavorites.STRING_KEY));
  }

}
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggesions.

Comment: How is this any different from simply specifying a static (or configurable) set of allowable `Class<?>`s? You're just adding a wrapper to the `Class` object. I don't get it.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta He wants compile time safety for calls to `putFavorite` and `getFavorite`.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta It's part of a database client.  The keys are the classes of the objects returned from the database.  Actual method calls will be something like Subscription userSubscription = dbInterface.get(userId, RestrictedKeys.SUBSCRIPTION_KEY), or GeoLocation userGeoLocation = dbInterface.get(userId, RestrictedKeys.GEO_LOCATION).  The DB can only query for certain keys, and I wanted to enumerate them.