# return value in a list of generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a list (IParameterCollection) of generics(IParameter), which are supposed to be a parameter of something.
This generics have a "Type", which contain the type of which the actual parameter is.

```
enum Type {
    TEST1(Integer.class),
    TEST2(Double.class);

    Class<?> _clazz;

    private Type(Class<?> clazz) {
        _clazz = clazz;
    }
    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return _clazz;
    }
}

interface IParameterCollection {
    IParameter<?> getParameter(Type type);
}
interface IParameter<T> {
    public Type getID();
    public T getValue();
}
```

Is it somehow possible to call

```
IParameterCollection#getParameter(Type.TEST1).getValue()
```

and receive an object of the type Integer without casting it into one?

What I want to do:

I have an Effect that contains Parameters.
if I want to change the parameters I want to call getParameterCollection and receive IParameterCollection.

```
IParameterCollection parameters = effect.getParameterCollection();
```

now I ask that collection for a specific parameter

```
// should return the parameter with the generic type defined in the Type
IParameter<Integer> parameter = parameters.getParameter(Type.TEST1);
// should return Integer and not any unknown type
parameter.getValue();
```

**So depending on the Type I give into that method, the returntype should change.**

Comment: This is really unclear. What do you want to do exactly? Can you show us the implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting Keys in Type Safe Heterogenous Containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414076/limiting-keys-in-type-safe-heterogenous-containers). Also related: [Why shouldn't Java enum literals be able to have generic type parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters) and [Java enums and generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108733/java-enums-and-generics).

Comment: Thank you Paul, thats what I was searching for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414076/limiting-keys-in-type-safe-heterogenous-containers

Answer (score -1):

If all you're trying to do is avoid having to cast, you can do this:

```
public <T> IParameter<T> getParameter(Type type);
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
IParameter<Integer> parameter = parameters.getParameter(Type.TEST1);
```

But basically, you're just hiding your casting. If you cast things incorrectly, you'll find out as you pull items out of the collection.

Comment: I don't just want to hide it. The "Type" knows the type of the parameter.

Comment: Because of erasure, hiding the casting is almost all you can get in this situation. The "type" information is almost purely a compile-type artifact. Thanks for the downvote, by the way -- it's a great way to encourage responses.

Comment: @bcholmes Actually, I'm the downvoter. I downvoted because that signature forces an unchecked cast that can't be justified. While you allude to this in your answer, it's still bad code that someone might copy.